# Navigation title color

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have implemented a navigation controller through Drag and Drop, now I want to set the my own custom colour of RGB:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.992 green:0.443 blue:0.173 alpha:1.0].
```

while I implement the following code it gives me another Color.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.992 green:0.443 blue:0.173 alpha:1.0]}];
```

How can i get my required color...?

Comment: What color does it show?

Comment: (0.992, 0.443, 0.173) is orange.

Comment: Nope its light blue

Comment: when i set it , its shows orange

Comment: Why do you think (0.992, 0.443, 0.173) is light blue?

Comment: i have given it to a label text  and tried

Comment: text color is light blue

Comment: Try it here http://output.jsbin.com/ilowi5/3

Comment: when i implement [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.992 green:0.443 blue:0.173 alpha:1.0]}];

Comment: i am getting orange

Comment: Voting to close, as setting an orange color is doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

The RGB you are setting is of Orange color ,

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.992 green:0.443 blue:0.173 alpha:1.0].
```

This means  R = 253 G = 113 B = 44 
Check it on this [link](http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html)

For Light blue color this will help .
`R=164`  , `G=224` , `B= 254` .

You need to code like this

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:164/255.0f green:224/255.0f  blue:254/255.0f  alpha:1.0].
```

Hope this Helps!